# Click on progress bar and know the timer of the video before (and after)

Tags: javascript, video.js, dom-events

I'm using Videojs and I need to know when the timeline is used to navigate. Especialy I want the "current time" of the player when I click on the bar, and also the timer where it has been clicked (but easy one, I'll explain)

By using the myPlayer.currentTime() I can get the timer of the video, so I with eventListener such as "onclick" or "onmousedown" I though I can get the timer of the video at the click. But it only give me the timer after.

It's not easy to explain so this is an example :
[progressbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7LEh.png)
The timer is currently 0:01, and I click at 0:14
How to get the "0:01" from the player, which event

This is my event but I get the new timer

```
myPlayer.controlBar.progressControl.on('mouseup', function (event) {
            console.log(myPlayer.currentTime());
});
```

I even try other event, on other elements such as mousedown which also give me the timer after, and not triggered when I click directly on the slider

```
myPlayer.controlBar.progressControl.on('mousedown', function (event) {
            console.log(myPlayer.currentTime());
});
```

I've tried lots of things, none of them work, have you any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The VideoJS library offers a nifty little event that can be useful for your use-case: **timeupdate**.

Just set up a global variable **previousTime** and update it each time the timeupdate event fires. As soon as you click on the progressbar you can get the time via previousTime.

```
var previousTime;
myPlayer.controlBar.progressControl.on('mousedown', function(event) {
  console.log("previous: " + previousTime + " current:" + myPlayer.currentTime());
});

myPlayer.on("timeupdate", function(e) {
  previousTime = myPlayer.currentTime();
});
```

Comment: Yes it kind of works but if I click directly on the slider the event is not detected (with mouseup it is , I don't understand why they are about the same, unfortunatly mouseup is triggered to late)

Comment: Solution find ! By doing the same on myPlayer.controlBar.progressControl.seekBar
Strange tho